# Apply discount if 2 of the different item from a category are added

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-community, shopping

I'm looking to build the following Shopping Cart Rule and I have no idea how to do it.
I have multiple sku available, if you add 2 different sku in your cart from the same category, you get 10% off. It can be any combination of sku,any quantity , and the discount is only applied once.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this configuration would work for you. You'll need to set your own categories, of course, but the format should work to qualify your discount for carts that contain 2 or more items from the target category(ies).
[image]

Now, if you *only* want the discount to apply to those qualifying products (and not the whole cart), then you will need to build a similar construct in the "Actions" panel so that the discount will only apply to products in the cart that match your criteria.

Comment: configurable products wont be add to cart every time i used this rules.

Comment: Configurable products won't add; the simple product that is associated with the configurable product will. Configurables are virtual products, not actual products. Make sure the associated products are assigned to the same category you're using for your promotion condition. When a customer Adds a Configurable to their shopping cart, they're actually adding the simple product chosen in the configurable Product Detail. Keep that in mind.

Comment: this will apply even if a product with 2 quantity is purchased